# Codeigniter error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\application\controllers\user.php on line 14

```
<?php

class User extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->user_model->(2);
    }
```

Comment: Do we have a space after parent:: & __construct & also what's the method name you are calling of user_model in get() function??

Comment: Is `user_model` a function or you forgot to place a function over there

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `user_model` be a function, it should be

```
$this->user_model(2);
```

Or be the **model**, you are missing the function name. Should be -

```
$this->user_model->your_function(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$this->user_model->(2);
```

should be

```
$this->user_model->your_method_name();
```

and inside `()` you can ***pass parameters*** as well

**Example :**

**In controller**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$this->user_model->your_method_name($name,$address, $phone);
```

**In Model**

```
function your_method_name($name,$address, $phone)
{
    //your query

}
```